# References from Precompiled DLL

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I've successfully built a Precompiled Function (DLL) and but ran into some issues regarding Reference from my DLL to other .Net Framework libraries.

I first tried to promote only my DLL to Azure and that failed due to missing dependancies. Next I tried to use Reflector to list the actual dependancies of my DLL and include them with Nuget but ended up just copying every DLL from my project bin directory to Azure and it worked.

So what how do I tell what libraries are actually included by the Azure Function environment and which I need to Nuget or upload myself.  I couldn't find any documentation on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

With the pre-compiled model, you need to bring your dependencies with the assembly where your function is defined (much like deploying a console or standard Web Application).

The simplest approach is to deploy the files from your assembly's output folder. The Azure Functions Tools for Visual Studio 2017 will do exactly that for you, giving you the ability to publish directly from VS.

Comment: Please let us know if this doesn't answer your question.